# Xcode "Build and Archive" button disabled for Mac app. Why?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, build, archive

I am building a Mac app, but the "Build and Archive" menu item is disabled. I am running Xcode  3.2.4 and OS X 10.6.5. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download and install the "Application Tools" package fixed it for me.

Links to the Application Tools download can be found on the index page for the Mac developer program.